# React: Why is the argument empty when calling the function in the onClick event?

Tags: reactjs

I have setup a table and perform a function based on a table row click and this works. I have now added a checkbox to each table row and want to perform a function on clicking this checkbox, however, it calls the function but the argument is empty whereas on the table row click the same construct does work.

```
  renderIndustryListItems() {
    return this.props.industries.map((industry) => {
      return (
        <tr className="table__tr" key={industry._id} id={industry._id}
          onClick={(evt) => this.handleIndustryClick(industry, evt)}>
          <td className="table__td">
            <input type="checkbox" onClick={(evt) => this.handleCheckboxClick(industry, evt)} />
          </td>
          <td className="table__td">{industry.name}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  }

  handleIndustryClick(industry, e) {
    this.setState({id: industry._id, industry: {_id: industry._id, name: industry.name}});
  }

  handleCheckboxClick(industry, e) {
    alert('Industry:', industry);
  }
```

Since I am using the same methodology in the onClick of the input as on the table row, I would have expected it to work. Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Try using `onChange` and `checked` for checkbox as shown here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#handling-multiple-inputs

Comment: yeah try onChange It should work.

Comment: @Edwin, are you just trying to use the alert() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think its an issue with your event-handler. Assuming you really are trying to `alert()` something, that built-in function only accepts one argument, so adding a comma to display your obj separately definitely would not work.

You can use a template literal to achieve want you want:

```
 handleCheckboxClick(industry, e) {
    alert(`Industry is ${industry.name}`);
  }
```

Codesandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/zxl2owp2np

Comment: Thanks Christopher. You are right. I used alert incorrectly. Other than that it is fine.